# Passing inbound query string to outbound links

Tags: html, query-string, session-variables

Inbound visitors are arriving at our website with a query string that serve as credentials.  (e.g.oursite.com/landingpage.php?id=abc&token=def)

After visiting pages in any order, they arrive at a final page with an outbound link that we wish to have the same query string appended to.
(e.g. a href="nextsite.com/targetpage.php?id=abc&token=def" ...)

What is the most effective way to keep track of the query string name value pairs as they visit other pages in order to reconstruct it on the outbound links?  (The attribute names of the name-value pairs will remain unchanged for all users.)  Is it to put them into session data?  Code examples for how to save and how to retrieve would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the parameters of interest in a session. This way it suffices if the user visits the page with the query string attached but internal links don't need to pass it around as well.

I assume you're using php.

You can store a key-value query parameter (if set) in the global session array like this:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['key']))
{
    $_SESSION['key'] = $_GET['key'];
}
```

And retreive it like:

```
session_start();
$value = $_SESSION['key']
```

Remember you need `session_start` only once per page but before any call to the session array!